# Warning with CGContextSetLineDash

Tags: swift, cgcontext, ios-charts

I'm trying to implement graph in my app. I had used this [graph](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) library in my app. It's working properly, but it shows following warning for 15-20 time in console.

```
CGContextSetLineDash: invalid dash array: at least one element must be non-zero.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should post what are the argument values.

As I can assume from the error message, your arguments has 0 and is not allowed. Read CGContextSetLineDash about the dash options.

```
// This dash shouldn't be zero
line1.lineDashLengths = [0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks @wingzero. You are correct. My code contains lineDashLengths = [0.0, 0.0]. On commenting it all the warning removed.